# SQL - Normalization Trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-normalization

I'm creating fantasy football game and I have a question about how to design my database. I'm having difficulty designing a way to share players between leagues and still have it be normalized.

There is a table  with all the possible football players called Players, a table that contains team information called Teams, a table that contains user information called Users, a table that contains league information and a table that keeps all the other tables id's called Rosters.

Basically there is a league that has a set amount of players, once the draft starts the players get set to a team and if they belong to a team they can no longer be drafted. The problem I'm having is, sharing these players with multiple leagues. Currently  I have a boolean value set to the player if they are available or not. Which works until another league try to draft that player, because they have been set to unavailable.

My question is how should I make the player available/unavailable in the database so that different leagues have the same player selection ? Is there a better way of setting up this database ?

Rosters

```
CREATE TABLE Rosters ( 
RostersID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
LeagueID INT NOT,
TeamID INT NOT NULL , 
PlayerID INT NOT NULL , 
UserID INT NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (RostersID)
)
```

Leagues

```
CREATE TABLE Leagues ( 
LeagueID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
LeagueName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,  
PRIMARY KEY (LeagueID)
)
```

Teams

```
CREATE TABLE Teams (
 TeamID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 TeamName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,
 StateCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL ,
 Ranking INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
 PRIMARY KEY (TeamID)
)
```

Users

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
 UserID  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 UserName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
 Email VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
 Password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
)
```

Players

```
CREATE TABLE Players ( 
 PlayerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 LastName VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
 FirstName VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
 Postion VARCHAR NULL ,
 Available BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE ,
 PRIMARY KEY (PlayerID)
)
```

Comment: "make the player unavailable in the database so that different leagues can draft the same players". Does not compute.

Comment: Different leagues have the same player selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a database level question, this is a task for the application logic. What you can do on a database level is to place a multi column unique constraint in the `roster`  table on `leagueid, playerid` fields. This would prevent your application to assign the same player to the same league twice. Get rid of the `available` field.

The available players for a league can be listed by left joining the players table on the roster table:

```
select p.playerid
from players p
left join rosters r on p.playerid=r.playerid and r.leagueid=...
where r.playerid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the relationship between players and leagues out into a separate table perhaps named LeaguePlayer and move the available flag to there. Then modify the ROSTER table to reference LeaguePlayer rather than Player.

If you then constrain the database so that the LeaguePlayerId on the roster table is unique.  Then create a unique constraint on LeaguePlayer for both reference columns.  This would prevent duplicates within leagues whilst allowing different leagues to include the same player.

Optionally you could remove the available flag and infer that a player is available by their LeaguePlayerId not occurring in the roster table.

Example code below.

```
CREATE TABLE Rosters ( 
RostersID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
LeagueID INT NOT,
TeamID INT NOT NULL , 
LeaguePlayerID INT NOT NULL , 
UserID INT NOT NULL , 
UNIQUE(LeaguePlayerID),
PRIMARY KEY (RostersID)
)

CREATE TABLE LeaguePlayer (
LeaguePlayerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCRMENT,
LeagueId INT NOT NULL,
PlayerId INT NOT NULL,
Available BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
UNIQUE(LeagueId,PlayerId),
PRIMARY KEY (LeaguePlayerID)
)
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing a hybrid solution of your diea and Shadows, where i broke up the databases a bit more and got rid of the Roster table. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

With your table structure you can create a table LeaguePlayer which contains the playerID and leagueID with appropriate foreign keys and a composite primary key. 
When pooling players for draft you call a query like

```
SELECT p.playerID FROM player p LEFT JOIN LeagePlayer lp ON p.playerID
= lp.playerID WHERE lp.leagueID = current_league
```

Answer (score 0):

There are "1:many" relationships, and there are "many:many" relationships.  You must decided whether team:player is 1:many or many:many.  You have design `Roster` with all sorts of many:many relationships possible.

Instead, the `Player` table should have a column `team_id`, thereby signaling that it is a 1:many relationship (1 team : many players).

Since you are talking about Teams picking Players, you might want to indicate that a Player has not been picked by having `team_id` be `NULL`.

Comment: So Team should have PlayerID and i should remove PlayerID from Roster. Should i also remove UserID from Roser and put it in Team and/or League?

Comment: Also Does that mean i should take Team out of Roster and put TeamID inside League, because there should only be 1  team per league ?

Comment: I think you need to start over in the design of the schema.